# Usage of "paid" and "paid for"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, direct-objects, indirect-objects

Why is it "paid for" and not "paid" in this sentence:

> Bobo has repaired and repainted the car, but when the woman goes to take out her wallet, the boy shakes his head and says, “It’s already been paid for."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb **paid** takes objects that are *the method of payment*: credit cards, cash, seashells, etc. You could say "The **money** has already been **paid**."

The verb **paid for** takes objects that are *the reason for the payment*, in this case the service of repairing and repainting the car: "The **service** has already been **paid for**."

Comment: If I want to ask a question that whether a car has already been paid for or not, then is this a correct question: Is this car already been paid for?

Comment: @Ganesh, you would be correct, **but** "is" is present tense and "been paid for" is past tense. You can actually use either one, but you have to be consistent: *Is this car paid for?* or *Has this car been paid for?*

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use "for" depends on what "it" refers to. If "it" refers to the bill, then it's just "It's been paid". If "it" refers to the repairs, then it's "It's been paid for".